# Empty Cart Link Not working (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, shopping-cart

I am unsure why this button isn't working.  I am getting the following error:
"No route matches [DELETE] "/cart.599""  and in my routes I have the carts resource.  Any idea why this isn't working?

_cartmodal.html.haml

```
= link_to 'EMPTY CART', cart_path(@cart), method: :delete, class: 'small-caution-btn', confirm: 'Are you sure?'
```

carts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @cart = current_cart
    @cart.destroy
    session[:cart_id] = nil

    respond_to do |format|
      if (current_user.try(:admin?) || current_user.try(:employee?))
        format.html { redirect_to manager_dashboard_path, notice: "Your cart is currently empty." }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: "Your cart is currently empty." }
      end
      format.js
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: `resources :products, :collections, :images, :orders, :carts, :line_items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
= link_to 'EMPTY CART', @cart, method: :delete, class: 'small-caution-btn', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Also the `confirm` option should be in a `data` hash.

Comment: I am still getting a Routing Error:
  `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/cart.599"):1`

Comment: It really sounds like you use the route `resource :carts` instead of `resources :carts` but you say you don't. Sure there are no other conflicting routes defined?

Comment: repository right [here](https://github.com/blklane/r9) and definitely do resources with carts as plural... I am really mystified with this one.

Comment: What if you remove this line from `routes.rb`: `get '/cart' => 'carts#mycart', as: :cart`. I think that is the conflicting route.

Comment: yup that was it.   How should I handle that then?

`as: :my_cart`?

Comment: Yup, `:my_cart` won't conflict with other routes.

Answer (score 0):

What your seeing means the cart_path helper is not expecting to get an argument. The @cart object is being interpreted as the format of the url (html, json, xml, etc.) which is why it's generated as a suffix (/cart.599  instead of /carts/599).

Does your routes file declare the cart resource as

```
resource :cart
```

or

```
resources :cart
```

In this case 'resources' is likely to be correct. 'resource' is for singular resources and would result in the situation you are seeing. It might be something else, it's impossible to tell without seeing your routes file, but this is a pretty common mistake.

Comment: I have all my resources listed on one line in my routes.rb file like so:
  `resources :products, :collections, :images, :orders, :carts, :line_items`
So I think I'm good there.